# How to set data in a way that after refresh also It stays there in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to make a react project with node and mongo where I will show elements of my periodic table onclick I would update link and show popup with data. Here is the json data

```
{
    "elements": [
        {
            "name": "Hydrogen", 
            "appearance": "colorless gas", 
            "atomic_mass": 1.008, 
            "boil": 20.271, 
            "category": "diatomic nonmetal", 
            "color": null, 
            "density": 0.08988, 
            "discovered_by": "Henry Cavendish", 
            "melt": 13.99, 
            "molar_heat": 28.836, 
            "named_by": "Antoine Lavoisier", 
            "number": 1, 
            "period": 1, 
            "phase": "Gas", 
            "source": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen", 
            "spectral_img": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Hydrogen_Spectra.jpg", 
            "summary": "Hydrogen is a chemical element with chemical symbol H and atomic number 1. With an atomic weight of 1.00794 u, hydrogen is the lightest element on the periodic table. Its monatomic form (H) is the most abundant chemical substance in the Universe, constituting roughly 75% of all baryonic mass.", 
            "symbol": "H", 
            "xpos": 1, 
            "ypos": 1, 
            "shells": [
                1
            ],
            "electron_configuration": "1s1",
            "electron_affinity": 72.769,
            "electronegativity_pauling": 2.20,
            "ionization_energies": [
                1312.0
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "name": "Helium", 
            "appearance": "colorless gas, exhibiting a red-orange glow when placed in a high-voltage electric field", 
            "atomic_mass": 4.0026022, 
            "boil": 4.222, 
            "category": "noble gas", 
            "color": null, 
            "density": 0.1786, 
            "discovered_by": "Pierre Janssen", 
            "melt": 0.95, 
            "molar_heat": null, 
            "named_by": null, 
            "number": 2, 
            "period": 1, 
            "phase": "Gas", 
            "source": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helium", 
            "spectral_img": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Helium_spectrum.jpg", 
            "summary": "Helium is a chemical element with symbol He and atomic number 2. It is a colorless, odorless, tasteless, non-toxic, inert, monatomic gas that heads the noble gas group in the periodic table. Its boiling and melting points are the lowest among all the elements.", 
            "symbol": "He", 
            "xpos": 18, 
            "ypos": 1, 
            "shells": [
                2
            ],
            "electron_configuration": "1s2",
            "electron_affinity": -48,
            "electronegativity_pauling": null,
            "ionization_energies": [
                 2372.3, 
                 5250.5
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "name": "Lithium", 
            "appearance": "silvery-white", 
            "atomic_mass": 6.94, 
            "boil": 1603, 
            "category": "alkali metal", 
            "color": null, 
            "density": 0.534, 
            "discovered_by": "Johan August Arfwedson", 
            "melt": 453.65, 
            "molar_heat": 24.86, 
            "named_by": null, 
            "number": 3, 
            "period": 2, 
            "phase": "Solid", 
            "source": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithium", 
            "spectral_img": null, 
            "summary": "Lithium (from Greek:\u03bb\u03af\u03b8\u03bf\u03c2 lithos, \"stone\") is a chemical element with the symbol Li and atomic number 3. It is a soft, silver-white metal belonging to the alkali metal group of chemical elements. Under standard conditions it is the lightest metal and the least dense solid element.", 
            "symbol": "Li", 
            "xpos": 1, 
            "ypos": 2, 
            "shells": [
                2,
                1
            ],
            "electron_configuration": "1s2 2s1",
            "electron_affinity": 59.6326,
            "electronegativity_pauling": 0.98,
            "ionization_energies": [
                520.2, 
                7298.1,
                11815.0

            ]
        }]}
```

The problem in my code is whenever somebody sets URL manually It wont get default popup with data. I want the urls to be dynamic but be accessible. I am using the element name as react link which is redirected to route on call by passing details of elements to be shown in popup.

Here are my files for react 
**App.js**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import axios from 'axios';
import Element from './components/Element';
function App() {
  // const context = React.createContext();
  const [elements, setElements] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const res = async () => {
      const result = await axios.get('/data');
      const data = result.data;
      setElements(elements => [...elements, ...data]);
    };
    res();
  }, []);
  // console.log(elements.map(element => console.log(element)));
  return (
    <div className='wrapper'>
      <div id='table'>
        {elements.map(element => (
          <Element elements={element} key={element._id} />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

In App.js I am fetching the data and mapping it to send to the element to be shown in front end.

**Element.js**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Redirect,
  Route,
  Link
} from 'react-router-dom';
import Popup from './Popup';
const Element = ({ elements }) => {
  const { symbol, category, name, number } = elements;
  const [showPopup, setPopup] = useState(false);
  const test = window.location.pathname;
  console.log(abc === '/' ? 'yes' : 'no');
  const handleClick = () => {
    setPopup(!showPopup);
  };
  return (
    <Router>
      <div
        onClick={() => handleClick()}
        title={name}
        className={`element element-${number} ${category}`}
      >
        {' '}
        <Link to={name}>
          <div className='symbol'>{symbol}</div>
        </Link>
        {showPopup ? (
          <Route
            exact
            path='/:name'
            component={() => <Popup element={elements} />}
          />
        ) : (
          <Redirect to='/' />
        )}
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
};

export default Element;
```

In Element.js I am trying to get the props from app.js and on click on any element I am showing data  and updating link. when they click again I make the popup variable as false and thus redirecting to home page.

**Popup.js**

```
import React from 'react';
// import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
const Popup = ({ element }) => {
  console.log(element);
  const { category } = element;
  return (
    <div className='popup'>
      <center>
        <div className={`popupInner ${category}`}>
          {Object.entries(element).map(([key, val]) => (
            <h2 key={key}>
              {key}: {val ? val : 'unknown'}
            </h2>
          ))}
        </div>
      </center>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Popup;
```

In Popup.js I am showing the data details by mapping through the contents.

Please tell me how can I do that? I am redirecting to '/' when showPopup is false. Please provide suggestions and description with the code.

Comment: Like any JS that needs "data on reload/page load", store the data (e.g. locally using localStorage or indexedDB, or remotely on firebase or the like), and then check if there's anything that needs restoring when your React app/component mounts. Alternatively, don't roll your own solution and instead start using a dedicated store like Redux. Lots of tutorials and articles about this subject on the internet, Google should let you find plenty of them.

Comment: If I store the data in local storage but somebody shares the URL to someone else then the other party won't be able to use It that is what I want to avoid.

Comment: Okay? But you're using mongo already, what's preventing you from storing the state there and updating it as people interact with it? Set up an API route that allows the browser request the state, and call that route during component startup so you can bootstrap the component state if the server reports there's data there.

Comment: That will be too heavy for n number of users besides for a new user It will not show popup even If we share the link. I guess using localStorage would do atleast for the current user.